# Java, rounding a double to two decimal places

Tags: java

I'm trying to round a double to the nearest two decimal places however, it is just rounding to the nearest full number.

For example, 19634.0 instead of 19634.95.

This is the current code I use for the rounding

```
double area = Math.round(Math.PI*Radius()*Radius()*100)/100;
```

I can't see where i am going wrong.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Insert 100.0d where relevant. And read up on casting rules.

Comment: Is that the problem? Casting rules say the int will be upcast.

Comment: have you had a look at RoundingMode class? if you use BigDecimal it's much easier  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Yes, so with `float / int`, the int is upcast to float.

Comment: Do you need to round for math reasons or display reasons?

Comment: Whoops, you're correct. Round produces an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, `Math.round(Math.PI*Radius()*Radius()*100)` is `long`. `100` is `int`.

So `Math.round(Math.PI*Radius()*Radius()*100) / 100` will become `long` (`19634`).

Change it to `Math.round(Math.PI*Radius()*Radius()*100) / 100.0`. `100.0` is `double`, and the result will also be `double` (`19634.95`).

Comment: Apart from the minor mistake pointed out by @IvanKoblik this is the only answer that correctly explains the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually want want to round the value to 2 places, which will cause snowballing rounding errors in your code, or simply display the number with 2 decimal places? Check out `String.format()`. Complex but very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DecimalFormat` object:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits (2);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits (2);

System.out.println (df.format (19634.95));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the `DecimalFormat` class.

```
double x = 4.654;

DecimalFormat twoDigitFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println("x=" + twoDigitFormat.format());
```

This gives "x=4.65". The difference between `#` and `0` in the pattern is that the zeros are always displayed and # will  not if the last ones are 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following example came from [this forum](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/4130-rounding-double-two-decimal-places.html), but seems to be what you are looking for.

```
 double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
      DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
      return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
 }
```